# How to analyze difference in answers between groups across multiple Likert questions? Categorical PCA and Chi Sq?

Tags: r, pca, chi-squared-test, factor-analysis, likert

I'm analyzing [this dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/wiki4he) from UCI ML Repo. It's on the perception of Wikipedia amongst university professors/instructors. I'm looking to test the differences between departments in their answers to 5 "Use" questions, mostly pertaining to whether they would have their students use Wikipedia in their classes.

At the end of this post is the code to the analysis I've done so far. I first visualized the distribution of each Likert question without and with regards to the departments. Then I conducted a Chi Sq test to see if departments answered one of the questions differently (at least one did). Then I did a post hoc test to see which departments differed (Law and Politics stands out).

My question is how can I test for a difference across all 5 questions at once? I thought a Categorical PCA might help, or at least affirm that the 5 questions indeed represent a single over-arching question on Wikipedia perception. The CATPCA's first pc captures 66.2% of the variation, with the next largest capturing only 14.5%, so I think the questions map to the same thing.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

```
library(tidyverse); library(likert); library(fifer); library(Gifi)

# Preprocessing. DOMAIN (Department) and 5 Use questions will be used.

wiki <- read_delim("wiki4HE.csv", delim=';')

wiki[wiki=='?'] <- NA

wiki$DOMAIN <- factor(wiki$DOMAIN, labels=c('Arts & Humanities', 'Sciences', 'Health Sciences', 'Engineering & Architecture', 'Law & Politics', 'other'))

wiki[,11:53] <- lapply(wiki[,11:53],ordered)



# Convert questions to likert data and plot

wiki_qs <- cbind(wiki[,substr(names(wiki), 1,2) == 'Us'])

names(wiki_qs) <- c(
  Use1="I use Wikipedia to develop my teaching materials",
  Use2="I use Wikipedia as a platform to develop educational activities with students",
  Use3="I recommend my students to use Wikipedia",
  Use4="I recommend my colleagues to use Wikipedia",
  Use5="I agree my students can use Wikipedia in my courses")

wiki_likert_qs <- likert(wiki_qs)

plot(wiki_likert_qs)



# Make plot of questions by department. Only 2 questions selected to make plot more readable.

the_nas <- which(is.na(wiki$DOMAIN))

wiki_likert <- likert(wiki_qs[-the_nas,c(1:2)], grouping=wiki$DOMAIN[-the_nas])

plot(wiki_likert)



# Chi-square test for one question, Use3. Reject H0, so at least one department gave a different distribution of answers.
mytable <- table(wiki$DOMAIN, wiki$Use3)
mytable

mytest <- chisq.test(mytable)
mytest$residuals

sig <- .05
sigAdj <- sig/(nrow(mytable)*ncol(mytable))
qnorm(sigAdj)


# Post-hoc test and plot. Law and Politics stands out as disliking Wikipedia.
chisq.post.hoc(mytable, test = "chisq.test")
mosaicplot(mytable, shade=T)


# Categorical PCA of the Use questions to check that they answer same overarching question. First pc captures 66% of variance.
# wiki was a table and df, needs to only be df for princals().
data_for_pca <- as.data.frame(na.omit(wiki[c("Use1","Use2","Use3","Use4","Use5")]))

use_pca <- princals(data_for_pca)
use_pca

summary(use_pca)

plot(use_pca, "screeplot")
```